# CQ5 - sling:OsgiConfig service in Java class

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I have created a sling:OsgiConfig node which is having a property paths of type String[]. I need to access this property in a java class. I want to make a method in java class that I would call from my JSP.  I am doing this using taglib. I know we can achieve the same in JSP using the code below:

```
    Configuration conf = sling.getService(org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin.class).getConfiguration("Name of the config");
String[] myProp = (String[]) conf.getProperties().get("propertyPath");
```

How can I do this in a Java class.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't said in what type of Java class you'd like to get the configuration. Let's go through options:

**1. Any OSGi service (like servlet, filter or event listener)**

Add following field to the OSGi component class:

```
@Reference
private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;
```

and use it in the same way as in the JSP.

**2. OSGi service to which the sling:OsgiConfig belongs**

If you added `sling:OsgiConfig` node to configure your own OSGi component, follow Chris advice:

```
@Component
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "propertyPath")
})
public class MyComponent {

    private String[] propertyPath;

    @Activate
    public void activate(ComponentContext ctx) {
        propertyPath = PropertiesUtil.toStringArray(context.getProperties().get("propertyPath"));
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // do something with the propertyPath field
    }
}
```

The activate method is invoked automatically by the OSGi. Qualified name of `ComponentContext` is [`org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentContext.html)

**3. Plain Old Java Object**

If your class is not an OSGi component, you need to have access at least to the `SlingHttpServletRequest` object. If you do, you can extract `SlingScriptHelper` from it and use it to obtain `ConfigurationAdmin`:

```
SlingHttpServletRequest request = ...;
SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings) request.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName());
SlingScriptHelper sling = bindings.getSling();
// here you can use your JSP code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that code in the activate method of your service.  You can identify your class as a service by using annotations.

```
@Component(label = "Title", description = "Description.", immediate = true, metatype = true, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
@Service(value = {YourServiceInterface.class})
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "propertyPath", label = "Property Label", description = "Property Desc.")
})
```

Then you can define an activate method to pull them out.

```
protected void activate(ComponentContext context) throws RepositoryException {
    String[] myProp = (String[])context.getProperties().get("propertyPath");
    // or
    String[] myProp = PropertiesUtil.toStringArray(context.getProperties().get("propertyPath"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Chris. Could you please let me know if this ComponentContext belongs to com.day.cq.wcm.api.components. Since I could not find the method getProperties() in this ComponentContext. Also, once I have the value of propertyPath, how can I fetch this value in some other method. Do I have to call activate method ?

Comment: I believe this is the import you will need.
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;